# Convert Date DD/MM/YYYY to 7 Digit Julian Date in Perl

Tags: perl, julian-date

I have not used Julian date before and have no experience with it. I do not know how the 7-Digit needs to be converted or if there is a library that does it.

I require help with 10/10/2020 to be converted to 2459133 in Perl.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Julian::Simple

Comment: Thanks. It is working and it brings back 2459132.5

Comment: @Pierre: Installing a CPAN module seems unnecessary when Time::Piece will do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Time::Piece](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time::Piece) is part of the standard Perl library.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

# Get a Time::Piece object from your date string
my $d = Time::Piece->strptime('10/10/2020', '%d/%m/%Y');

# Call its julian_day() method.
say $d->julian_day;
```